# Why do we need Lebesgue to claim that the length of $\mathbb Q$ is $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Since we know that $\mathbb Q=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\{x_n\}$ (i.e. it's countable), why do we need Lebesgue to say that $\mathbb Q$ has length $0$ ? Indeed, if $$\operatorname{Length}(\mathbb Q)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\operatorname{Length}(\{x_i\})=0,$$
since $\operatorname{Length}\{x_i\}=0$. So if this is not valid, how should the length of a set be defined?

Comment: Do you mean measure instead of length?

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure

Comment: @dmtri: no, really Length. Like $Length[a,b]=b-a$. Because to compute the length of $\mathbb Q$ we need Lebesgue measure. So why it has no sense before Lebesgue to compute the length of $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: this would be true if your notion of length would be countable additive, that is, that you can add countable many times a length to get the length of the whole. This is the case when we define the length of a set in the real line using the Lebesgue measure

Comment: @Masacroso: I don't get it. Let define the length of a set $A$ as follow : Let $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}[a_n,b_n]$ where $[a_n,b_n]$ are almost disjoint. Then $Length (A)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}(b_n-a_n)$. This definition would make sense. As follow, then $$Length(\mathbb Q)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}(x_n-x_n)=0.\tag{*}$$ Why it doesn't work ? Maybe the length can be defined as $Length(A)=\int 1_A(x)dx$ (where the integral is interpretated in Riemann sense) ? And thus, indeed, $Length(\mathbb Q)$ wouldn't be defined. But I don't get why $(*)$ is not well defined.

Comment: @sam it works. I didnt said it didnt work, I said that it depends on your notion of length. If you are using the notion of your comment then yes, the length of $\Bbb Q$ is zero. It also depends a bit in the accepted notion of interval, but it is common to accept sets like $\{x_n\}$ as intervals, so its fine.

Comment: @Masacroso : So it's strange that we had to wait Lebesgue to say that the length of $\mathbb Q$ is $0$. And I imagine that my definition $(*)$ doesn't work for a reason I ignore, otherwise we didn't have waited Lebesgue. :)

Comment: what is "Lebesgue" for you? Why you think your definition "doesn't work"? Im saying it works. However your definition cannot be applied to sets composed by the union of uncountable many intervals (or separable points)

Comment: @Masacroso : Maybe to define the Length of a set as $Length(A)=\int\boldsymbol 1_A (x)dx$ with a Riemann integral would explain why we wait the theory of measure of Lebesgue to calcuate the length on $\mathbb Q$, no ?

Comment: @Masacroso: In the link you mention It's written that $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ is not Jordan measurable, so how can it be $0$ with Jordan measure ?

Comment: @sam you are right, I deleted my last comment. What Im trying to say is that the notion of "waiting" is very confusing. I dont know if some one give length zero to $\Bbb Q$ before Lebesgue theory, but what is clear is that the Lebesgue theory was the first theory (or one of the firsts) to give a reasonable value to the length of sets as $\Bbb Q$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a great question - basically, you're starting the thought process which will *ultimately lead to* the full theory of Lebesgue measure/integration. You're right that that full theory isn't needed for simple examples, but those simple examples are not as simple as they first appear, and the full theory does develop naturally out of the analysis of those simple examples we're forced to do.

---

There are a couple points here *(and, following you, I'm going to use "length" to describe the concept we're trying to pin down)*:

- First of all, the claim $$\mbox{"The length of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $0$ since $Length(\mathbb{Q})=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}Length(\{x_n\})=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}0=0$"}$$ is extremely problematic - consider the "clearly false" claim $$\mbox{"The length of $\mathbb{R}$ is $0$ since $Length(\mathbb{R})=\sum_{r\in\mathbb{R}}Length(\{r\})=\sum_{r\in\mathbb{R}}0=0$."}$$ The difference between these two claims - the first of which seems right, the second of which seems stupid - is the **additivity assumptions** they're each making: the first says that length is *countably additive*, while the second says that length is *continuum additive*. So **this reveals that we need to limit additivity** - and hence think about it in some detail - if we're going to get a non-silly notion of length.

  - Actually, even countable additivity is problematic, as seen by the construction of [Vitali sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). But that's a more subtle issue; I just want to emphasize that although your claim is extremely intuitive, it's hiding some real mathematical assumptions.
- More technically, the idea that we can satisfyingly set $Length(A)=\int_A1_A(x)dx$ using a *Riemann* integral is not going to work here - the indicator function of the rationals isn't Riemann integrable! So while it should certainly be true that $Length(A)=\int_A1_A(x)dx_{Riemann}$ *when the latter exists*, that's not going to serve us as a general definition.

So the point is that $(i)$ our existing notion of integration isn't up to the task and $(ii)$ we have genuinely interesting technical issues (additivity) we need to resolve. Now we **do not need** the full theory of Lebesgue measure/integration here - the rules "the length of a single point is $0$" and "length is countably additive" already imply $Length(\mathbb{Q})=0$ - but nobody ever claimed we do (to my knowledge); rather, Lebesgue measure/integration is the **natural ending point** of this line of thought.

*(Well, "ending point" is a bit strong - but it represents a coherent, fairly complete technical idea which ties all these issues together and gets new interesting results.)*

Comment: "nobody ever claimed it was": I can't find the referent of your "it" here! I think your sentence is ill-formed :-) +1, notwithstanding.

Comment: @TonyK Derp, fixed!

Comment: Proving that we can assign lengths in a meaningful way to sets on the line means somehow constructing the lebesgue measure. So I agree completely with your answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is that Lebesgue's definition of measure (or length, if you insist) is obvious. Yes, it is, in retrospect! But Lebesgue was the first to define it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Therefore, I say that Rimann integral of $\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q}$ $$\int \boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q}(x)dx=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\int_{x_i}^{x_i}1dx=0,$$ But it seem not to work.

Comment: @sam The function $1_\mathbb{Q}$ **isn't** Riemann integrable!

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I see my mistake (I wanted to define riemann integral of $\boldsymbol 1_\mathbb Q$ and to me this definition was good). I thought that if $(f_n)$ was a sequence of step function that converge to $f$, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b f_n=\int_a^b f.\tag{*}$$ But it's true only if $(f_n)$ converge uniformly to $f$ and here $\sum_{k=1}^n \boldsymbol 1_{\{x_i\}}$ is not converging uniformly to $\boldsymbol  1_{\mathbb Q} $. A small question, if $f$ is riemann integrable and $f_n$ is a sequence of step function that converge pointwise to $f$. Does $(*)$ hold ?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Then I see (and for compact domain this can be prove with dominated converge theorem right ?). And if $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $f_n$ are step function, then $f$ is automatically riemann integrable and we can permute limit and integral even in non compact domain ? (like $\mathbb R$)

Comment: @sam: Riemann integrals have nothing to do with step functions! The notion of a step function was introduced by Lebesgue.

Comment: @TonyK : Don't you confuse with simple function ?

Comment: @sam My previous comment was wrong, even more is needed: consider the function $f_n$ which is a "really tall triangle" from $0$ to ${1\over n}$ and is $0$ from ${1\over n}$ to $1$. You need quite strong assumptions on the sequence to conclude that things work out nicely (e.g. compact domain, continuous bounded functions).

Comment: @sam: No I don't.